# Value2 BETWEEN (Value1 - 5) AND (Value1 + 5)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, between

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table1 D1 (nolock)
WHERE  1 = 1
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM   Table2 D2 (nolock)
WHERE  d1.Account = d2.Account
    AND d2.Amount BETWEEN ( d1.Amount - 5 ) AND ( d1.Amount + 5 )
    AND Datediff(DD, d1.SALEDATE, d2.SALEDATE) BETWEEN 0 AND 60)
```

I've removed a lot of the functionality that isn't relevant to the question.

Essentially I want it to find records when certain criteria are met in the first part (I'm using 1=1 for simplicity here) and then exclude anything that has had a sale in the last 60 days for an amount -/+ $5 on the same account.

For some reason it simply returns 0 records every time, but upon examining the database table manually, this is not true. I am using Transact SQL.

Comment: Is it possible you've got your difference backwards? (i.e. it should be `between -60 and 0` - or reverse `d1` and `d2`)

Comment: Make no difference to the results. I've used Datediff hundreds of times in this way and no problems. This is the first time I am using an expression with d2.Amount BETWEEN ( d1.Amount - 5 ) AND ( d1.Amount + 5 ).

Comment: No problem. Was just a stab in the dark. Can you give us an example dataset to work with?

Comment: I can't provide the data as it is from a confidential source. I even had to change the names of fields/columns to protect privacy of the source etc. I'm just stumped completely why this wouldn't work.. I'm more of a programmer than a DBA, so I thought maybe I was trying to do something that was programmatically good but simply doesn't work in the context of a SELECT statement in SQL..

Comment: Ok, solved it... so simple...

I forgot to exclude the results from D1.

So now it has a d2.indexkey <> d1.indexkey statement and it all works.. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved it... so simple... I forgot to exclude the results from D1. So now it has a d2.indexkey <> d1.indexkey statement and it all works.. lol

Comment: Definitely wouldn't have noticed that from your reduced example, especially if it was actually a self-join. (You have two *different* tables in the question). Glad you solved it though.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It's my first time posting here and I was trying to hide the confidential workings of things.. it's hard to ask questions of people when dealing with confidential processes and data :(

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you use temp table for self join or sub query for that though your database processing ratio will be decreased and you will get faster result.

```
SELECT * into #temp
FROM   Table1 D1


select * from #temp t1
WHERE  t1.id not in(
    SELECT t2.id
        FROM    #temp t2
    WHERE  t1.Account = t2.Account
        AND t2.Amount BETWEEN ( t1.Amount - 5 ) AND ( t1.Amount + 5 )
        AND Datediff(DD, t1.SALEDATE, t2.SALEDATE) BETWEEN 0 AND 60)
```

However this is just alternate to your query.

**Advantages of temp tables**

- The table "exists" - that is, it's materialized as a table, at least in memory, which contains the result set and can be reused.
- In some cases, performance can be improved or blocking reduced when you have to perform some elaborate transformation on the data - for example, if you want to fetch a 'snapshot' set of rows out of a base table that is busy, and then do some complicated calculation on that set, there can be less contention if you get the rows out of the base table and unlock it as quickly as possible, then do the work independently. In some cases the overhead of a real temp table is small relative to the advantage in concurrency.
- Temp tables, while they have space assigned to them in the tempDB database, will generally be accessed only from memory, unless the server is under memory pressure, or the amount of data in the table is large.

Comment: Does using temp table/Physical table makes any difference performance wise?? can you please explain or provide some reference ?

Comment: Added few of the benefits why we prefer temp table.

Comment: ... and inline tables will _also_ generally be accessed also from memory. Inline tables will also be reused if they end up in memory. What you are suggesting is that loading _every_ column into a temp table will be quicker than using `EXISTS` (which is smart enough to only access the minimum of data required in the pages)

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea about the #temp tables. It has given me the ability to create a smaller, more relevant, dataset for the sub-query to go through and as a consequence, sped up the query by many factors of magnitude.

So now I have:

SELECT * INTO #Temp from Table1
WHERE SaleDate > '20150101'
AND CompanyKey = 123
GO

At the beginning. Then in the sub-query, I do a select on the #temp Table. These tables are all static data that gets refreshed at midnight, so there is no issues in using it like this.

Thanks again.